# Getting error java.lang.AbstractMethodError on ReportClientDocument.open() call

Tags: java, intellij-idea, crystal-reports

I am trying to autopost a crystal report in PDF formate.
I am using IDE: IntelliJ Gradle

```
 public void runApprovedSupplierSiteReport(){
    // final Config config = ConfigFactory.instance(Config.class);

     //CrystalUtil.setupJdbcJndi(Config.getDatabaseServer(), Config.getDatabaseUsername(), Config.getDatabasePassword(), Config.getDatabaseJdbcDriver(), Config.getDatabaseJdbcUrl());

    final List<String> paramNames = Config.getMatches(APPROVED_SUPPLIER_SITE_PARAM_REGEX);
    final Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    for (final String name : paramNames) {
        final String value = Config.getPqp_Report_ApprovedSupplierSite_Param_$0_Value(name);
        params.put(name, value);
    }

    final ReportClientDocument reportDoc = new ReportClientDocument();
    try {
        // export PDF
        final String report = Config.getPqp_Report_ApprovedSupplierSite_Rpt();
        reportDoc.open(report, OpenReportOptions._openAsReadOnly);
        CrystalUtil.setParamFields(reportDoc, params);
        final InputStream is = reportDoc.getPrintOutputController().export(ReportExportFormat.PDF);

        //
        final Session session = CmisUtil.createSession(Config.getPdmsAtomPubUrl(), Config.getPdmsUser(), Config.getPdmsPassword(), Config.getPdmsRepositoryId());
        final Map<String, Object> properties = DocumentManager.getDocumentProperties(
                DocType.SUPPLIER_REPORTS,
                DocGroup.MQPSD,
                SUPPLIER_REPORT_DOC_NUMBER,
                SUPPLIER_REPORT_NAME,
                new Date());

        final String prefix = ConfigUtil.getEnvironmentPrefix(Config.getTwsEnvironmentCode());
        final String docName = prefix + String.format(DocFormat.SUPPLIER_REPORTS, PdmsUtil.getDateAsString(new Date()));
        final Document document = CmisUtil.createDocument(
                session,
                docName + ".pdf",
                "",
                docName,
                DocClass.REPORTS,
                MediaType.PDF.toString(),
                is,
                -1,
                properties);
        Monitor.getLogger().info("<- PDMS report=" + report + " id=" + document.getId() + " versionSeriesId=" + document.getVersionSeriesId());

    } catch (final ReportSDKException e) {
        String err = e.getMessage();
        Monitor.getLogger().error("runApprovedSupplierSiteReport() " + e.getMessage());
        logger.error("runApprovedSupplierSiteReport()", e);
    } catch (final CmisBaseException e) {
        Monitor.getLogger().error("runApprovedSupplierSiteReport() " + e.getErrorContent());
        logger.error("runApprovedSupplierSiteReport()", e);
    } finally {
        CrystalUtil.closeQuietly(reportDoc);
    }
}
```

In above code snippet at line `reportDoc.open(report, OpenReportOptions._openAsReadOnly);` I got following error :

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.setProductLocale(Ljava/util/Locale;)V

at com.crystaldecisions.proxy.remoteagent.z.a(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportAppSession.int(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportAppSession.initialize(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ClientDocument.new(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportClientDocument.new(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ClientDocument.open(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.reports.sdk.ReportClientDocument.open(SourceFile:80)
at com.processstream.pepsico.pqp.tws.ows.PqpOwsJob.runApprovedSupplierSiteReport(PqpOwsJob.java:264)
at com.processstream.pepsico.pqp.tws.ows.PqpOwsJobTest.runApprovedSupplierSiteReport_1(PqpOwsJobTest.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

I have checked for all abstract classes but all the methods are defined. Please let me know if anybody can help me in solving this error.

Comment: Did you read the Javadoc for `AbstractMethodError`? It explains the cause.

Answer (score 0):

```
void com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.setProductLocale(Locale)
```

This method is concrete in the version of the library you used to compile your code, so your IDE was happy to compile a call reference to it.

The library present in the deployment location is a different version in which this method is abstract.

This is described in the Javadoc for `AbstractMethodError`:

> Thrown when an application tries to call an abstract method. Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of some class has incompatibly changed since the currently executing method was last compiled.

Comment: Yes i know about the AbstractMethodError but I am not sure exactly which jar is giving this problem.

Comment: The issue resolved. I changed the rasapp.jar and rascore.jar. :)