# Getting error java.lang.AbstractMethodError on ReportClientDocument.open() call on Crystal Report 2016

Tags: java, linux, crystal-reports, report

I am working on an old project recently. It generates the Crystal Report by using Java Crystal Report JDK.

And I met issue like below:

Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.setProductLocale(Ljava/util/Locale;)V
at com.crystaldecisions.proxy.remoteagent.z.a(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportAppSession.int(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportAppSession.initialize(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ClientDocument.new(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportClientDocument.new(Unknown Source)
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ClientDocument.open(Unknown Source)
at com.fwd.fsm.components.crystal.CrystalReportInvoker.init(CrystalReportInvoker.java:116)
at com.fwd.fsm.components.report.util.ReportInvoker.doExecute(ReportInvoker.java:64)
at com.fwd.fsm.components.report.util.ReportInvoker.doExecute(ReportInvoker.java:39)
at com.fwd.fsm.systemcommon.service.AbstractService.execute(AbstractService.java:402)

Exactly same as: [Getting error java.lang.AbstractMethodError on ReportClientDocument.open() call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37110446/getting-error-java-lang-abstractmethoderror-on-reportclientdocument-open-call/37110574)

I saw an answer that it got resolved by updating the rasapp.jar and rascore.jar.
I've tried to search on web and both SAP web site, but not able to find any.

Can I know where to install the rasapp.jar and rascore.jar?

Thanks in advance for helping.